# Rarely find position on Android devices while moving (walking/cycling/driving)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, geolocation, gps

I really hope that it's not too broad, but I have tried lots of things in order to detect the user's position.

I have installed the official https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation that was made by Apache Cordova.

But there tons of issues using this.

Just for example: Android on moving (walking/driving/cycling) has chances of 1/20 to detect the user's position. Rest of them will end with timeout error.
On Wifi it finds the position immediately, but the challenge is to find when he moves, on a watch position!
I have tried to enable High accuracy mode,
I have tried to get a position with good reception, but both didn't to the trick.

I wonder how Cordova developers are getting their user's position, LIVE, on motion? Is there any good plugin for this?
Since the plugin I have linked above is really useless if the position is not getting find, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You right, html geolocation plugin is not very precise on some device depending.

So i recommend you to use "cordova-plugin-advanced-geolocation" for Android Only.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-advanced-geolocation

Code sample :

https://github.com/Esri/cordova-plugin-advanced-geolocation/blob/master/sample/map.js

Comment: I will give this a try. I have not tested the plugin I have mentioned in real iOS device, but there should be no problem right?
More thing, how is this: https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt have you tried this? Thanks.